# Finding source of data in SSAS tabular

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, business-intelligence, ssas-tabular

I have the following table in SSAS tabular using visual studio.

I would like to find out what source table Customer name uses as it seems to be using a wrong table, but I can't figure out how to find out which table it uses from.

[image: my SSAS table]

[picture of property window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vn7gr.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

View the properties window.  To display this, highlight the table in SSDT then go to **View** > **Properties Window** or press **F4**.  After this, find the Source Data field and click the ellipsis next to it.  This will open a window that will display either the source table/view, stored procedure EXEC statement, or SQL command that the table is derived from.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the property window seems to be missing the Data Source field (screenshoted as newest picture on original post). my version of VS is 2015.

Comment: On the top menu, if you select "View" do you see the "Properties Window" option?

Comment: I do and I have opened it, however I do not see the data source field. I've updated my original post with a screenshot (named picture of property window). Could it be because I use a different version of Visual Studio?